# Error in conversion of time format from full calendar start time to C# timespan

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, momentjs

Im trying to convert event start time returned by fullcalendar to model bind with c# timespan object in an action method. The format in which fullcalendar is assigning the value to start time is "May 24, 2015 6:30 AM". But in the ModelState im getting following error "The value 'May 24, 2015 6:30 AM' is not valid for StartTime.". In the event modal i have to display start time in the above said format (May 24, 2015 6:30 AM). but want it to model bind properly to Timespan object. Any help regarding this.

Some more information regarding the scenario:

This is the code i have in calendar javascript to display custom date time format
$("#StartTimeTxtBox").val(moment(start).format('LLL')); which displays time as 'May 24, 2015 6:30 AM'. Im trying to bind this to  "public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }" in my action method and it results in the error "The value 'May 24, 2015 6:30 AM' is not valid for StartTime.". Is there any way to convert before binding to the server variable?`enter code here`

Update #1: Im posting the part of code for more clarity.

In full calendar javascript:

```
    select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    $('#modalTitle').html("Add a new event");
                    //$('#modalBody').html("Hello world");
                    $("#StartTimeTxtBox").val(moment(start).format('LLL'));
                    $("#EndTimeTxtBox").val(moment(end).format('LLL'));
                    $('#AppointmentDate').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
                    $("#PatientStatement").val('Please add some description about illness');
                    $("#DoctorClinicID").val('@ViewBag.DoctorClinicID');
                    $('#calendarModal').modal();               
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
```

Markup for the StartTime Text box:
    `<input type='text' id="StartTimeTxtBox" class="form-control sharp-edge" placeholder="Start Time" name="StartTime" />`

C# View model:

```
    public class AppointmentModel
        {
            public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
            public int DoctorClinicID { get; set; }
            public string DoctorName { get; set; }
            public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime Start
            {
                get
                {
                    var ret = AppointmentDate;
                    ret = ret.Add(StartTime);
                    return ret;
                }
            }
            public DateTime End
            {
                get
                {
                    var ret = AppointmentDate;
                    ret = ret.Add(EndTime);
                    return ret;
                }
            }
            public int PatientID { get; set; }
            public string PatientName { get; set; }
            public AppointmentStatus Status { get; set; }
            public int TokenNumber { get; set; }
            public string PatientStatement { get; set; }
            public string ClinicComments { get; set; }
        }
```

Action Method:

```
    public JsonResult SaveAppointment(AppointmentModel appointmentModel)
            {
                int appointmentID = 0;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Appointment appointment = new Appointment
                    {
                        AppointmentDate = appointmentModel.AppointmentDate,
                        StartTime = appointmentModel.StartTime,
                        EndTime = appointmentModel.EndTime,
                        AppointmentStatusID = 1,
                        ClinicComments = appointmentModel.ClinicComments,
                        DoctorClinicID = appointmentModel.DoctorClinicID,
                        PatientID = appointmentModel.PatientID,
                        PatientStatement = appointmentModel.PatientStatement,

                    };
                    appointmentID = repository.SaveAppointment(appointment);
                }

                return Json(appointmentID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: I can convert the timespan to date time in this case, but still as gaiazov mentioned, it would still not bind properly

Comment: `hh:mm` format should correctly deserialize into a `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LT` or `hh:mm` momentjs format instead of `LLL`. The LLL format includes the date component and you just need the time component.

e.g. change

```
$("#StartTimeTxtBox").val(moment(start).format('LLL'));
$("#EndTimeTxtBox").val(moment(end).format('LLL'));
$('#AppointmentDate').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```

to

```
$("#StartTimeTxtBox").val(moment(start).format('LT'));
$("#EndTimeTxtBox").val(moment(end).format('LT'));
$('#AppointmentDate').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

or

```
$("#StartTimeTxtBox").val(moment(start).format('hh:mm'));
$("#EndTimeTxtBox").val(moment(end).format('hh:mm'));
$('#AppointmentDate').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Comment: But this wont display in the above reqiured format(May 24, 2015 6:30 AM).Any way to display in the said manner and model bind it in your way. Or is using delimiter the only option in the action method.

Comment: In that case, you can use hidden fields for values you want to send to the server

Comment: So to spice up things a bit :), i also use bootstrap-datetimepicker for those text boxes, so that the user can also change the values using datetimepicker, but again in the same format. So according to your solution i should be using jquery events to replicate the value of the textbox in some hidden field in a proper format and then model bind it?